# Set custom height for \n line break in raw text

Tags: html, css

I'm using a `line-height` property and `white-space: pre-line;` on a raw text. 
I would like to get a different height for each `\n` lines without using individual `div` or `br`.
 I want to be able to distinct between a newline `\n` and a `wrap` line resulting from text being larger than the div.
I've included a snippet with the raw code and the desired result.

Thank you

```css
.natural {
    width: 70vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5vw;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.875rem;
    white-space: pre-line;
    background-color: grey;
}

.artificial {
    width: 70vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5vw;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.875rem;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.newbreakheight {
margin-bottom: 0.9375rem;
}
```

```html
RAW
<div class="natural"><b>This is a text and this is the end of the line (\n).</b>
This is another line that will go on until it reaches the edges of the div and eventually wrap unto a next line. (\n).

I would like to be able to specify the height of all \n lines above using css.
</div>

DESIRED
<div class="artificial"><b><div class="newbreakheight">This is a text and this is the end of the line (\n).</b></div>
<div class="newbreakheight">This is another line that will go on until it reaches the edges of the div and eventually wrap unto a next line. (\n).
<div class="newbreakheight">
<br>
I would like to be able to specify the height of all \n lines above using css.<div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think i will search for /\n\r?/g in raw text using js and see if can solve the pb from there

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to affect the distance between individual lines of text in a single HTML text node.